# Memoizing a recursive function for a game algorithm?

Tags: java, recursion, memoization

I have a a working recursive function for an assignment. However, part of the requirement is to get the complexity down by utilizing memoization.

The function works similarly to a mobile tapping game. Users can perform either a) a tap b) an upgrade. The function finds the least number of taps to get to a specified amount. Users can skip levels - hence bypassing the cost for that level.

For example:

```
Levels: 0, 1, 2.
Cost of upgrades: 0, 5, 8.
Money per tap: 2, 4, 9.
```

One of the routes, with required amount $15:

- Tap thrice to get $2 x 3 dollars. ($6 left.)
- Upgrade for $5 ($1 left.)
- Tap twice to get $4 * 2 + $1 dollars. ($9 left.)
- Upgrade for $8 ($1 left.)
- Tap twice to reach the required amount ($19 > $15.)

Total of 3 + 2 + 2 = 7 taps.

A more efficient route will be:

- Tap four times to get $2 x 4 dollars. ($8 left.)
- Upgrade for $8, skip level two upgrade. ($0 left.)
- Tap twice to reach required amount ($18 > $15.)

Total of 4 + 2 = 6 taps.

Now I have a working recursive program for the above. I tried memoizing the program by using a 2D array `cache[levels][amount]` , where the taps for each levels/amount is stored and access when needed.

A minimal working solution is as follows:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.*;

class IdleGame {

  private static int fork(int current, int required, int level, int taps, int[] values, int[] costs, int maxLevel,
      int[][] cache) {
    int first = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int second = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    if (current >= required) {
      return taps;
    }
    //upgrade path, call recursively if available.
        for (int i = level + 1; i <= maxLevel; i++) {
  if (current >= costs[i]) {
    if (cache[i][current] == 0) {
      first = fork(current - costs[i], required, i, taps, values, costs, maxLevel, cache);
      cache[i][current] = first;
    } else {
      // System.out.println("First");
      first = cache[i][current];
    }
  }
}

if (cache[level][current] == 0) {
  second = fork(current + values[level], required, level, taps + 1, values, costs, maxLevel, cache);
  cache[level][current] = second;
} else {
  // System.out.println("Second");
  second = cache[level][current]--;
}

    return first < second ? first : second;
  };

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      int[] values = {2,4,9};
      int[] costs = {0,5,8};
      int[][] cache = new int[3][16];
      int solution = fork(0, 15, 0, 0, values, costs, 2, cache);
          System.out.println(solution);
    }
}
```

However, this solution is not quick enough for my test case. As far as I can tell, I am using the memoized values when there is another instance of a recursive function calling the same `level/value`, this happens when two recursively functions cross i.e. have the same parameters.

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you only store the second value, but not the first? Or is that already your issue?

Comment: The first value does not actually modify the number of taps i.e. it's just an upgrade path (so only the cost is modified). After the upgrade, the function is called recursively again and this time around, it will fall under the `second` case.

Comment: What does it matter what the first value is? You are recalculating it everytime the method is called with the same values and that kind of misses the whole point of memoization.

Comment: Do you mean i should try to add the `if/else` memoization to the upgrade (first) block? I did that and I still fail my time complexity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see a reason why you only store the `second` value, but not the `first`. Actually you should simply store the end result and check for it at the beginning of the method:

```
private static int fork(int current, int required, int level, int taps, int[] values, int[] costs, int maxLevel, int[][] cache) {

    if (current >= required)
        return taps;

    // check cache, calculate value only if cache is empty
    if (cache[level][current] == 0) {

        // calculate first value
        int first = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (int i = level + 1; i <= maxLevel; i++) {
            if (current >= costs[i]) {
                first = fork(current - costs[i], required, i, taps, values, costs, maxLevel, cache);
            }
        }

        // calculate second value
        int second = fork(current + values[level], required, level, taps + 1, values, costs, maxLevel, cache);

        // store result in cache
        cache[level][current] = first < second ? first : second;
    }

    // return cached value
    return cache[level][current];
}
```

Btw, checking if the cache is set by checking if the value is 0, is not a good idea in general. What if a valid result actually can be 0? It's better to use a nullable type or a container that can be checked for a key existing or not.

Another thing I noticed is that depending on your inputs, you are repeatedly overwriting `first` in that loop, as you have no break condition. So you recalculate `first` for every `costs[i]` that is smaller than `current`. You should make sure to find the *one* `costs[i]` you want, and calculate `first` only for that. If you just want to find the first `costs[i]` smaller than `current`, simply add a `break`:

```
for (int i = level + 1; i <= maxLevel; i++) {
    if (current >= costs[i]) {
        first = fork(current - costs[i], required, i, taps, values, costs, maxLevel, cache);
        break;
    }
}
```

If you want to find the smallest `costs[i]` smaller than `current`, you need to store the index and call `fork` after the loop:

```
// find smallest costs[i] smaller than current:
int smallestCostIndex = -1;
int smallestCost = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for (int i = level + 1; i <= maxLevel; i++) {
    if (current >= costs[i] && costs[i] < smallestCost) {
        smallestCost = costs[i];
        smallestCostIndex = i;
    }
}
// calculate first using smallest costs[i] smaller than current (if it exists):
int first = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
if (smallestCostIndex >= 0) {
    first = fork(current - costs[i], required, i, taps, values, costs, maxLevel, cache);
}
```

===

On a side note your code is a bit messy and could use some good refactoring for better readability. For example you might want to create a class for holding the primitive parameters and pass an instance of it to `fork`. Also proper collections are probably better than simple arrays. And since those collections (arrays) are always the same instance(s), you don't need to pass them as parameters. Make them members of your class and make fork a non-static method. Something like this:

```
class GameParams {
    private int current;
    private int required;
    private int level;
    private int taps;

    // constructor, getters etc.
}

class GameState {
    private int value;
    private int cost;

    // constructor, getters etc.
}

class Game {

    private int maxLevel;                   // initialized to 2 in your case
    private List<GameState> states;         // initialized to {GameState(2,0), GameState(4,5), GameState(9,8)} in your case
    private Map<GameParams, int> cache;

    // constructor, getters etc.

    private int fork(GameParams params) {   // called with GameParams(0, 15, 0, 0)
        if (chache.contains(params))
            return cache.get(params);

        // ...
    }

}
```

Take this last bit with a grain of salt, I just typed it down as some form of guidance for a OOP approach to your code.

Comment: Much effort for a relatively specific question. OP should be grateful you have taken the time.

Comment: I've run the code from the first revision of  the question. There were 4 chache hits. Running the code from your answer I am getting only 3 cache hits (in case `cache[level][current] != 0`). But it also has one call of `fork` less. Maybe therefore ... (still +1)